# Paypal IPN HTTP/1.1 - doesn't provide any response at all, it is an empty string

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

**This unexplainable probably affects or will affect thousands of webmasters.**

The problem is Paypal doesn't give a response to this request AT ALL. Below is the sample code I use and also my programmer's comments:

"PayPal doesn't give any response to this request at all, an empty string comes from it. You may ask the PayPal team, if anything besides 'Host' and 'HTTP/1.1' should be added to handle response properly. Could it be that the 'cmd' command should have another value?
My expectation is that PayPal will open HTTP/1.1 protocols only in February 2013, as they state in their email. I'm not sure how the same script and host may handle different protocols. The script is not working now with HTTP/1.1 with the code we have on file, and the reason may be on PayPal's side.
I was following how PayPal queries the IPN script, and it seems that it goes into some kind of loop, when there's HTTP 1.1 set. You can still see it yourself in ipnlogz.txt - '07%3A39%3A41' - i.e. '07:39:41' date of my order - it's repeated 5 times! Why? Who knows... 
it only means PayPal was trying to IPN this script 5 times and with no success. There appeared 'VERIFIED' response from PayPal only when I've updated HTTP to 1.0 and re-uploaded the script. After that, PayPal was still querying it.
It seems when HTTP = 1.1 , PayPal is getting everything properly, but not responding properly; then for some reason gets back to create yet another response for the same payment. With HTTP 1.0 it's all like a flower: one request, one response, everything works. I don't know what's wrong with it...

Ps. We are not talking about an 'INVALID' response. An 'INVALID' response is actually part of success -but in the case of HTTP 1.1, PayPal doesn't provide any response at all, it is an empty string."

```
<?php

$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
$r='';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
$r.="{$key}: {$value}\n";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
#I also tried: $fp =fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com',443,$err_num,$err_str,30);

if (!$fp) {
$r.="----\nHTTP ERROR\n";
// HTTP ERROR
} else {

$r.="----\nReceived IPN request\n";

fputs ($fp, $header . $req);

while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
}
fclose ($fp);

if (strcmp ($res, 'VERIFIED') == 0) {

$proceed=TRUE;

}
else{
$proceed=FALSE;
}
}

?>
```

PS. This is the `notify_url` part of the script we use:

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="{$main_url}/index.php?action=ipn&amp;user_id={$user_id}" />
```

and when it was tested in Sandbox it is working..

Comment: On another forum someone suggested to change this: <input name="**notify_url**" type="hidden" value="script.php" /> to <input name="**ipn_notify_url**" type="hidden" value="script.php" /> but it doesn't work either...

Answer (score 12):

Change this:

```
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
#I also tried: $fp =fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com',443,$err_num,$err_str,30);
```

To this:

```
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

And this:

```
if (strcmp ($res, 'VERIFIED') == 0) {
```

To this:

```
if (strcmp (trim($res), 'VERIFIED') == 0) {
```

And it's pretty much guaranteed to work.

Your current setup fails because PayPal sends a Connection: keep-alive header in the response which fsockopen gladly accepts, and thus it keeps the connection open.
Whereas a HTTP library such as cURL will close the connection automatically.

My general suggestion is; if you don't want to control every single bit that goes across the line to PayPal, use a HTTP library such as cURL, rather than fsockopen which is just a plain TCP connection.
(PayPal has sample code using cURL available at https://www.paypal.com/ipn and https://www.paypal.com/pdt)

Comment: Hm, it worked in part (I still couldn't get the 'VERIFIED' response from Paypal). Maybe a combination of trim and this code above will get the final correct answer?

Comment: Tom, I tested this again to make sure, and it's working for me at the moment. Can you run a test again on your end?

Comment: I used fsockopen with the HTTP 1.0 API, and it worked great. But I couldn't get fsockopen to work with 1.1 (and I tried the updates you suggested above). However, 1.1 does work for me if I use cURL (similar to the code sample on paypal.com/ipn).

Answer (score 2):

In your code above you can replace:

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
```

With

```
if (strcmp (trim($res), "VERIFIED") == 0) {
```

The only difference is the trim

Answer (score 1):

I found this http://www.justmyusecase.com/2012/09/subject-action-required-update-your.html

Looks like you just need to trim the "verified" string.

Comment: Hm, you are onto something! Do you know how to trim this string to make it work?

Comment: I trimmed the string so that it is like: if (strcmp (trim($res), 'VERIFIED') == 0) { but I still don't get the 'VERIFIED' answer..

Answer (score 1):

I added the below line and this worked fine

$res = trim($res);

Ref Links

1. http://www.johnboy.com/blog/http-11-paypal-ipn-example-php-code
2. http://www.johnboy.com/scripts/paypal-ipn/paypal_ipn_1_1.phps

Answer (score 0):

Since middle of December 2012 we did not receive any IPN from PayPal.
There are no entries in the web servers access or error logs that indicates that PayPal is trying to send IPNs since then.

So i had a phone call with the german paypal support today (After more then 2 hours in the waiting line - i reached finally somebody).

**They confirmed to me, that there is a problem with some accounts (No sending of IPN) and that they try to fix it.
So before you try to change your Scripts, watchout for the server log files first!**

Answer (score 0):

well, I had something similar with my IPN

give a try and change IPN encoding on PayPal

my accont => my profile => my selling tools => language encoding

Answer (score -1):

I'm having this issue as well and PP refuses to acknowledge there is an issue. I don't know what to do, but customers will be mad in four months.

One change you should make is:

```
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n"; // wrong  
$header .= "POST cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n"; // right (according to PP)
```

Comment: Well, at least I know I'm not insane. The suggested change may be good, but it still doesn't resolve the problem..