# Why does tlstest.paypal.com work from browser but not from my PHP code (useful for Paypal IPN)?

Tags: php, ssl, paypal, paypal-ipn, tls1.2

After 2018 June 30th, Paypal [won't accept non-TLS 1.2 + HTTP 1.1 requests](https://www.paypal-notice.com/en/TLS-1.2-and-HTTP1.1-Upgrade/) anymore.
They created the URL https://tlstest.paypal.com/ to test if connections are OK. If we open this URL in a browser, we get a successful:

```
PayPal_Connection_OK
```

**Quesiton: why does it fail when connecting from PHP with the following code?** (I get no response at all, the browser is still in waiting "state" [like this](https://thomas.vanhoutte.be/miniblog/wp-content/uploads/spinningwheel.gif), so it doesn't even arrive at `echo $errno; echo $errstr;`)

```
<?php
$req = '';    // usually I use $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate'; for IPN
$header .= "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Host: tlstest.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen('tls://tlstest.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp) {
    echo $errno;
    echo $errstr;
} else {
    fputs($fp, $header);
    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        $res = fgets($fp, 1024);
        echo $res;
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Note:

- this is not a duplicate of [Paypal IPN HTTP/1.1 - doesn't provide any response at all, it is an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12480794), the latter is outdated.
- I have PHP 5.6.33-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Jan 5 2018 15:46:26) and `openssl version text: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016`

Comment: You should probably add some debug things in the first branch of the `if` which is currently empty. The `fsockopen` may not use TLS1.2 it can depend on many things like your PHP version that you do not disclose, nor how openssl was installed. And I think the main advice from the other question applies here too: `fsockopen` is too low as API, use a true HTTP client like  `curl`.

Comment: `why does it fail` **What fails**? You haven't actually explain what the error is. Are `errno` or `errstr` set? What do they contain?

Comment: Based on that - I assume that what will actually happen is that the page load will hang for 30 seconds ( the fsock timout ) before returning with a connection timeout error. Are you able to open a connection to any other host? On any port? Are you running on a VPS? Or on some shared web-host? It may be possible that firewall rules / access restriction policies may be blocking your outbound requests from the host. Reduce the 30 to 5 and confirm that the page hangs for 5 seconds before giving an error -

Comment: You need at least openssl 1.0.1 for TLS 1.2 support, print OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER it should be at lease 0x1000100. You have probably a too old version, PHP 5.5 is unsupported since 2 years now...

Comment: Why don't you want to use `curl` library from PHP? From same host, did you try on command line `wget`, `curl` or even `openssl s_client` to determine if the problem is with your code/libraries or if it is a network problem? Or did you try your code towards another host? Note that you probably need SNI in fact, did you check that?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I tried with `wget`, and it works: `PayPal_Connection_OK`. I think there's maybe a small typo / mistake in my PHP code, I would like to find it :) After having found the error, I'll be ok to move to `curl` library. But first I'd like to understand why the current code fails.

Comment: I do not think there is a code problem. I run it locally and got an HTTP reply as expected: `HTTP/1.1 426 Unknown
Server: AkamaiGHost
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 267
Expires: Fri, 22 Jun 2018 19:49:46 GMT
Date: Fri, 22 Jun 2018 19:49:46 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade: TLS/1.2` etc. The HTTP error by itself is probably due to missing SNI or something. But it shows the TLS connection working. This is with PHP 7.1.16 CLI.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I have the same but also at the end: `You don't have permission to access "http://tlstest.paypal.com/" on this server.` It should *not* be `http://tlstest....` but `https://...`! Is there something wrong in my code that says `http://` ?

Comment: I can only repeat what I said: `fsockopen` is probably a too low level library to do that, why reinventing all HTTP stuff when you have HTTP client libraries that do everything for you? Again, I suspect the issue comes from SNI (that `fsockopen` does not do I think) or something like that, see the `Upgrade` header it means it is not proper TLS/1.2 exchange. I see no point in having a lot of energy to make that work, even if possible, and then switch to a proper HTTP library. Switch to a proper HTTP library now!

Comment: I will follow your advice! Could you post an answer with (minimal) PHP working code with another library, that shows "Paypal_Connection_OK"? Thanks a lot in advance! This problem is bringing me headaches since months, because Paypal still send me emails "Update required: YES for 2018 June 30th". I'm sure it can help other people in the same situation too :)

Comment: @Basj A simple `file_get_contents('https://tlstest.paypal.com/')` should do. Beyond that, https://php.net/curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works on my side by changing `tls://` to `ssl://` which makes absolutely no sense to me, but this is also why using `fsockopen` is a too low level library to just do HTTP exchanges with it (you should use a proper HTTP client library) and at the same time not configurable enough regarding TLS stuff.

With
`$fp = fsockopen('tls://tlstest.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);`
I get :

```
HTTP/1.1 426 Unknown
Server: AkamaiGHost
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 267
Expires: Fri, 22 Jun 2018 19:49:46 GMT
Date: Fri, 22 Jun 2018 19:49:46 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade: TLS/1.2

<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;tlstest&#46;paypal&#46;com&#47;" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;8024a17&#46;1529696986&#46;1fc51318
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

but with `$fp = fsockopen('ssl://tlstest.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);`
I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 20
Date: Fri, 22 Jun 2018 20:05:35 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

And then it hangs, probably because it is a keep-alive connection and the buffer is smaller than 1024 so that you do not get the following body content.
Which is probably "PayPal_Connection_OK", as it exactly matches the length displayed in `Content-Length`.
This again shows that you should use an HTTP client library instead of trying to (badly) reimplement HTTP on top of `fsockopen`.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here is a working code (full credit to PatrickMevzek's answer):

```
<?php
$req = '';
$header = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Host: tlstest.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen('ssl://tlstest.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 3);

if (!$fp) {
    echo $errno;
    echo $errstr;
} else {
    fputs($fp, $header);
    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        $res = fgets($fp, 21);   // 21 because length of "PayPal_Connection_OK"
        echo $res;
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Here is the answer from server:

```
# php -f test.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 20
Date: Fri, 22 Jun 2018 20:19:56 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

PayPal_Connection_OK
```